# CentOs 5.11 mod_dav_svn update

Tags: svn, centos5, mod-dav-svn

I've Centos 5.11 with wasn't maintained by anyone.

```
cat /etc/*-release

CentOS release 5.11 (Final)
```

And I tried to update svn from 1.4.6 to 1.6.11 using yum.

```
sudo yum update subversion

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: centos.serverspace.co.uk
 * base: centos.hyve.com
 * epel: mirrors.coreix.net
 * extras: centos.hyve.com
 * rpmforge: www.mirrorservice.org
 * rpmforge-extras: www.mirrorservice.org
 * updates: centos.hyve.com
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
1581 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
--> Processing Dependency: subversion = 1.4.6-jason.1 for package: mod_dav_svn
--> Processing Dependency: subversion = 1.4.6-jason.1 for package: subversion-devel
---> Package subversion.x86_64 0:1.6.11-12.el5_10 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
--> Processing Dependency: subversion = 1.4.6-jason.1 for package: mod_dav_svn
---> Package subversion-devel.x86_64 0:1.6.11-12.el5_10 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
mod_dav_svn-1.4.6-jason.1.x86_64 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: subversion = 1.4.6-jason.1 is needed by package mod_dav_svn-1.4.6-jason.1.x86_64 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: subversion = 1.4.6-jason.1 is needed by package mod_dav_svn-1.4.6-jason.1.x86_64 (installed)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

So yeah, mod_dav_svn is installed with 1.4.6 version. Obviously I need to update it as well though yum doesn't give me any choice and lists only that version.

I've googled and tried [this](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21916#p103081) though without result.

*nixes are not my thing, I know basic stuff but fail when something isn't going the easiest way. Is there any way to update mod_dav_svn to match mentioned svn version?

EDIT:

I even tried installing [rpm](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-12.el5_10.x86_64.rpm) with `yum install <file-name>` yet it said:

```
Setting up Install Process
Examining mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-12.el5_10.x86_64.rpm: mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-12.el5_10.x86_64
Nothing to do
```

Comment: Look at the third party repositories. One of them is causing your problems.

Comment: Sorry but "Look at the third party repositories." doesn't tell me much.
What shall I look for and where to look?